# Resize HTML image published from Excel sheet via VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, resize, publish

Is there a way to resize a published .html file to fit the web browser window? I am publishing parts of an excel sheet via `PunlishObjects.Add`. When I open the .html in a web browser, the image is far too big. Manually changing the web browser zoom to fit the image every time is not a very good option. How do I set the size of the HTML file after or during the creation of it?

Comment: For this you need to adjust the size of your rows and columns in excel itself. Make sure that the range you want to publish fits your screen in excel.

Comment: All right. I was hoping for some smart property I could not find. But it is what it is. Thank you, Luuklag!